# How can I have a function/method append passwords to a different list depending on what class is using it?

Tags: python

I am making a password generator as my first stab at OOP in python. I have 3 classes `Simple`, `Complex` and `Memorable`. **Simple** is the parent to `Complex` and Memorable is also a child class of **Simple**. Both `Simple` and `Complex` have the same **generate** method to generate a password:

```
    def generate(self, num_of_passwords: int):
        characters = ''
        if self.characters is None:
            characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        else:
            characters = self.characters

        for i in range(num_of_passwords):
            password = ''
            for c in range(self.length):
                password += secrets.choice(characters)
            output.append(password)
        return output
```

Memorable has this generate function instead:

```
    def generate(self, num_of_passwords: int):
        word_url = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}
        req = urllib.request.Request(word_url, headers=headers)
        response = response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        long_txt = response.read().decode()
        words = long_txt.splitlines()

        for i in range(num_of_passwords):
            password = ''
            two_words = ''
            for i in range(2):
                two_words += secrets.choice(words).title()
            password = two_words
            if self.numbers == True:
                for i in range(random.randint(3, 4)):
                    password += secrets.choice(string.digits)
            output.append(password)
        return output
```

The **generate** functions above appends each password generated to a list called 'output'. output looks like this: `output = []`. The problem is all passwords are being appended to the exact same **list**. I know this could be solved easily by just having **3 different** lists for each **class** but is there a better way to do it? Thanks :D

Full code: (GitHub ----> https://github.com/lunAr-creator/pw-gen)

```
import random
import secrets
import string
import urllib.request

output = []

class Simple():
    def __init__(self, length: int, characters = None):
        self.length = length
        self.characters = characters

    def generate(self, num_of_passwords: int):
        characters = ''
        if self.characters is None:
            characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        else:
            characters = self.characters

        for i in range(num_of_passwords):
            password = ''
            for c in range(self.length):
                password += secrets.choice(characters)
            output.append(password)
        return output

    def return_result(self, index: int):
        return output[index]

    def clear_results(self):
        output.clear()

class Complex(Simple):
    def __init__(self, length, string_method, numbers=True, special_chars=False):
        characters = ''

        methods: dict = {
            "upper": string.ascii_uppercase,
            "lower": string.ascii_lowercase,
            "both": string.ascii_letters,
        }

        characters += methods[string_method]

        if numbers:
            characters += string.digits
        if special_chars:
            characters += string.punctuation

        super().__init__(length=length, characters=characters)

class Memorable(Simple):
    def __init__(self, numbers=True):
        self.numbers = numbers

    def generate(self, num_of_passwords: int):
        word_url = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}
        req = urllib.request.Request(word_url, headers=headers)
        response = response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        long_txt = response.read().decode()
        words = long_txt.splitlines()

        for i in range(num_of_passwords):
            password = ''
            two_words = ''
            for i in range(2):
                two_words += secrets.choice(words).title()
            password = two_words
            if self.numbers == True:
                for i in range(random.randint(3, 4)):
                    password += secrets.choice(string.digits)
            output.append(password)
        return output

# Test

c = Memorable()
print(c.generate(3))
print(c.return_result(1))
```

Comment: just add the `output` declaration to the init of each class. remove it from the global scope

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: in the base class class Simple():
    def __init__(self, length: int, characters = None):
        self.length = length
        self.characters = characters # add self.output = [] # remove the global one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append your generated passwords to output this way:

```
key = self.__class__.__name__
output.append({key:password}
```

This way, `key` would be the name of the class `self` is refering. If Complex herits from Simple, a Complex object will still prints "Complex" and the Simple objects will print "Simple" obviously.

Then, your set of passwords would be something like:

```
[{
   'Simple' : 'toto',
   'Complex': 'E341rfeq1zqer'
}]
```